# JS: Returning an object from a class instance but still accessing it's methods?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following class:

```
class NGPlayer {
  constructor(videoPlayerID, videoJSConfig, code) {
    this.player = videojs(videoPlayerID, videoJSConfig, code);
    return this.player;
  }

  setAutoplay() {
    this.player.getAXSMetrics().setTempo(true);
  }
}
```

my goal is to create an instance:

```
const foo = new NGPlayer(videoID, videoOptions, '232'); // this returns `this.player` from the constructor, which is the videojs object
```

I want to be able to also call `foo.setAutoplay()`.   Is it possible to do this from just setting the one variable, `foo` ?

Comment: Why are you returning `this.player` if that's not what you want? You can't do both.

Comment: `this.player` is what I want but then I have call additional methods on `this.player` later on.  `this.player` is the main object I need to pass around to load up the video player but then there's a block where I have to call a method on it to set autoplay and that method is directly on `this.player` (the videojs object)

Comment: Why not have an `setAutoplay(player)` function that you'd pass the player to? It sounds like a class isn't actually what you want then, just some helper functions.